# WebStorm: import/export statement in JavaScript

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm and a newbie to it. when I use **import/export** statements, it gives me an error of

```
Unexpected token import
```

but if I try with **require/module.exports** it works fine.

N.B- I've configured language version as ES6 from Languages and Frameworks.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This is not WebStorm but Node.js that fails. While `import` is a part of ES6, native support for ES6 modules in Node.js is very limited and requires special setup - see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling. So, you have to compile your code with Babel first. Usually transpiling is a part of build process (using Gulp, Grunt, WebPack, etc.). Or, you can transpile your code on-the-fly by passing `-r babel-register` to Node.js. Of course, you need creating appropriate `.babelrc` and install the required modules (`npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env`)